# PyCharm plot not showing entirely

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, data-visualization

I have this sample data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.rcdefaults()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Example data
people = ('Tom123456', 'Abraham123456', 'Harry123456', 'Slim123456', 'Jim123456')
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
error = np.random.rand(len(people))

ax.barh(y_pos, performance, xerr=error, align='center',
        color='green', ecolor='black')
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(people)
ax.invert_yaxis()  # labels read top-to-bottom
ax.set_xlabel('Performance')
ax.set_title('How fast do you want to go today?')

plt.show()
```

This is the graph in Jupyter Notebooks
[image: This is the graph in Jupyter Notebooks]

This is the graph in PyCharm
[image: This is the graph in PyCharm]

**How can I show the graph entirely in PyCharm?**

Comment: Add `plt.tight_layout()` before `plt.show()`?

Comment: It worked, but is there a way or settings on how I can configure in PyCharm?

Comment: I have never worked with PyCharm.

Comment: I also have this issue. I am using Pycharm Community and so do not have Scientific Mode available. As such plots show in a different window outside of pycharm.  That aside the issue is exactly the same in my case.